# jQuery plugin boilerplate who's my this?

Tags: jquery

I'm playing with a real simple jQuery plugin "hello world" but I have some troubles with [jQuery Plugin Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com). Even if plain simple and well commented I feel like I'm missing a point, for instance, I get errors whatever jQuery method I use. 
Here's my init function.

```
    Plugin.prototype = {

    init: function() {

        console.log(this, this.element); // this.element return my element works fine

        this.element.on('click', function() { // 'undefined' is not a function :(
            alert('whoa'); 
        });

        this.element.click(function() {  // not working at all :'(
            alert('whoa'); 
        });

    },

    open: function(el, options) {
        // some logic
    }
};
```

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: so jQuery plugin logic where's written: "there's no need to do $(this) because "this" is already a jquery object $(this) would be the same as $($('#element'));" isn't applicable to this boilerplate? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Can we see the `Plugin` function as well as your call to it?

Comment: here it is http://jqueryboilerplate.com

Comment: That framework you are using is different.  Normally, `this` is already a jQuery object, but here `this.element` is the native DOM element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a framework for making jQuery plugins, you're gonna have to follow their conventions.

If you were just doing `$.fn.plugin = function(){}`, then `this` would be a jQuery object, because `$.fn` is a reference to `jQuery.prototype`.

In your framework, `this.element` is the native DOM element, so to use jQuery methods, you need to wrap it in `$()`.

```
$(this.element).on('click', function(){
});
```